# Task.Factory.StartNew requires a lambda / Action?

Tags: c#, reference, lambda, action, taskfactory

I just fixed some production code, that wasn't working as expected. We are talking about a Windows service in .NET 4.5.1 written in C#. Although it's fixed, I'm trying to understand what happened. Some Googling didn't show much results on this. A task was being started as follows:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SendReminders);
 logger.Info("Waiting for sending to complete...");
 task.Wait();
```

To my knowledge, as in Threads, StartNew receives a reference to the method it should execute. Well this works in a debugging environment, but it doesn't in production (Release). The following did:

```
 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.SendReminders());
 logger.Info("Waiting for sending to complete...");
 task.Wait();
```

What am I missing here? Is code being optimized in a way that it isn't executed at all?

As requested, the body of the task method:

```
    internal void SendReminders()
    {
        using (this.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            try
            {
                var uow = container.GetInstance<UnitOfWork>();

                this.logger.Info("Sending reminders..");

                var handler = container.GetInstance<IHandleCommand<SendReminderCommand>>();
                handler.Handle(new SendReminderCommand());
                uow.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.Exception(ex);

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

So far no exceptions have been logged and the service was running. Using the Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SendReminders) line did not fire in production, but using the lambda worked like a charm.

I'm using SimpleInjector and the UnitOfWork is being backed by Entity Framework 6.0.2. The method that starts the task is being triggered by a Timer on the main thread.

Comment: Can you give use more context for the `StartNew` line? Can we also see the body of `DoSomeWork`?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work as expected ? this two code snippet does the same thing.

Comment: Exactly, I also expect both methods to work, but the first didn't somehow and I don't know why.

Comment: There is a race condition in your logging: _"Waiting for sending to complete..."_ may appear before _"Sending reminders.."_

Comment: There are a lot of things that can change when you hit a release configuration. Which logging messages are you missing?

Comment: I changed some naming for clearance, but you are right. But the logging in the sending method and deeper down in the commandhandler wasn't registered at all. People didn't receive e-mails, until I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an example of a deadlock induced by the blocking call to `Task.Wait`.

I'm not familiar with unity but calls such as `this.container.BeginLifetimeScope()` and `container.GetInstance<UnitOfWork>` may be invoking back to the entry thread. The release environment may be using a different `SynchronizationContext` to debug.

Its hard to tell without a working example of the behavior, but please try removing the call to `Task.Wait` and see what happens! It is generally accepted as better practice to use continuations to schedule work for after a `Task` completes.

```
//m_RemindersTask is a member of type Task
if(m_RemindersTask != null && m_RemindersTask.Status != TaskStatus.Running) //prevent simultaneous execution
{
    m_RemindersTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.SendReminders());
    logger.Info("Waiting for sending to complete...");
    task.ContiueWith(p => /*work to be done after the task*/, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); //this [optional parameter] makes sure that the continuation is run on the same thread that the scheduling method is run on, if possible.
}
else
    //Is Warning the correct method? You get the idea
    logger.Warning("Cannot send reminders: reminders are already being sent.");
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this. I wil investigate this further, becaus I need the Wait() to prevent the method running multiple tmes at the same time. Also, I'm using SimpleInjector and the UnitOfWork is being backed by Entity Framework 6.0.2. Excuse my lack of initial information.

Comment: Also the method that initiates the task is being triggered by a Timer object on the main thread.

Comment: `Wait` is unlikely to prevent the method from executing simultaneously - it is _not_ a `lock`. What `Timer` class are you using? I've edited in a solution to simultaneous running

Comment: It makes no sense to start a process on a new thread, and then to simply block the current thread until that process finishes. So definitely you need to get rid of the `Wait()`, whether it's causing the main problem or not (and it may well be, per Gusdor's comments).